# Can Glimpse provide diagnostics when using the SqlClient namespace classes

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, diagnostics, glimpse

I've downloaded Glimpse and the Glimpse.ADO extension and installed it on my test instance.

I thought I'd get a capture of any sql that was executed, but it seems like it doesn't capture commands with the way our code is written.

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) from table";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            txtResult2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I CAN get it to provide information from a test page with the sql code written like so:

```
        var factory =DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(cString.ProviderName);
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                txtResult1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
```

However I have too many places in my code to change if I can only capture data using this dbProviderFactories method.

Is there a way to get Glimpse.ADO to work with the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class? Is there another Glimpse extension that works with this namespace?

Is there another way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Just an observation: if there are too many places in your code that create a connection in a specific way, it may be a sign that your code is too repetitive.

Comment: Perhaps, but as someone smarter than I said, "Wherever you are, that's where you'll have to start"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @StriplingWarrior, leveraging the provider factories will make your code more DRY and follow best practices. `DbProviderFactories` really is the best way to do this and your code won't explicitly rely on Glimpse.

However, if you *really* want to just move forward with your existing app code, Glimpse will support you with the following changes:

```
using (var conn = new GlimpseDbConnection(new SqlConnection(cString))
{
    conn.Open();
    DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) from table";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    txtResult2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
}
```

In the example above, the command is created with the `CreateCommand()` method, which removes the need to associate the command and the connection.

Alternatively, you could also still explicitly create the command like so:

```
conn.Open();
DbCommand cmd = new GlimpseDbCommand(new SqlCommand());
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) from table";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Finally, more documentation about the SQL tab is available by clicking the `?` icon in the Glimpse UI when you have the tab selected, or by going to our [SQL documentation](http://getglimpse.com/Help/SQL-Tab) on [getGlimpse.com](http://getglimpse.com/). (**I'll be adding this info to that page for future reference.**)

Comment: What namespace is GlimpseDbConnection declared in?

Comment: `Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType` its in the `Glimpse.Ado` package.

Answer (score 1):

In problems section on Glimpse site...

Getting Glimpse to work with manual created SQL Connections/Commands

http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration